# if exist update else create for composite key

Tags: mysql, relational-database, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'am using this table(MySQL table) having 4 fields `(id, role_id, permission_id, status)` id is auto-increment corresponding to any `role_id` `permission_id` should never be duplicate i.e for `role_id` = 1, `permission_id` should be unique.

```
id | role_id | permission_id  | status
1  |     1   |       1        |   1
2  |     1   |       3        |   0
3  |     1   |       2        |   1
4  |     1   |       5        |   1
5  |     2   |       1        |   1
6  |     2   |       2        |   0
7  |     2   |       4        |   0
8  |     2   |       5        |   1
```

For implementing this i'am fetching object corresponding to particular `role_id`.
Now if we make any changes in status corresponding to any permission i want it to change in database, if any new permission id added a new row for that permission corresponding to that role id must be added in database in single query.
For eg -:

```
id | role_id | permission_id  | status
.  |     .   |       .        |   .
2  |     1   |       3        |   1
3  |     1   |       2        |   0
.  |     .   |       .        |   .
.  |     .   |       .        |   .
9  |     1   |       4        |   1
```

for `role_id` = 1 `permission_id` (3,2) are updated(toggled) and 4 is created.

At present i'am using 3 queries to do this task.

one to update the status from 1 to 0 if the permission was present in table but status was initially false and was made true later

second to update the status from 0 to 1 if the permission was present in table but status was initially true

third one to create a new row if that permission is not present.

Comment: First, create a `UNIQUE` index as appropriate. Secondly, use a [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) query for inserting rows.

Comment: ON DUPLICATE(for version> 5.7 and i'am using 5.6) is not working for me, is there any other way ?

Comment: It is available in both [5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and [5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: INSERT INTO `test` (`role_id`, `permission_id`, `status`) VALUES (1,4,0),(1,6,0),(1,5,0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status` = NOT status